# Deploying Workflow wsp as sandbox soluting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I Am Relatively new in sharepoint. I have created a small workflow using Visual Studio as a Farm Solution. It works fine for my Server but whem I am trying to deploy it on remote server its disabling the activate option ..it appears to me that i have to deploy it is as a sandbox Solution. I tried by setting  the sandbox = true in VS but then its throwing me an error saying "Feature cannot be deployed as Sandbox Solution". Can Any1 Help

Thank You